# Latest Tapjoy adapter not compiling in Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, libraries, tapjoy

I'm implementing Admob's mediation and I'm struggling to add the latest version of Tapjoy's adapter. The thing is, if I declare version 12.7.1.0 (old version), it works, but warns me there's a new version:

[image]

But if I change it to the latest version 12.8.0.0, it doesn't give any error while syncing. But it just doesn't launch the app with an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fixed by adding this to gradle repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://sdk.tapjoy.com/"
        }
    }
}
```

With only mavenCentral it seems to not throw any error but for version 12.8.0.0 or superior, tapjoy's maven repo is specifically needed